When does the equality hold in this matrix inequality?
For a matrix $U \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, $m\geq n$ with orthonormal columns. It can be shown that
$$
\dfrac{n}{m} \leq \max_{i = 1,\cdots m} \|U(i,:)\|^2 \leq 1.
$$
I conjecture that the upper bound is achieved iff $U = [I_{n}, \mathbf{0}_{n\times(m-n)}]^\top$ up to permutations and the lower bound is achieved iff each element of $U$ has the same modulus. But I had a hard time proving it rigorously. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

How about $m=n$, $U$ is any unitary matrix? Am I missing something?
